# thrift js:node - Cannot use reserved language keyword: "not"

Tags: node.js, thrift

When converting a thrift object for nodejs:

```
thrift -r --gen js:node state_service.thrift
```

The following error is thrown:

> [ERROR: /state_service.thrift:33] (last token was 'not') Cannot use
>   reserved language keyword: "not"

The lines in the code around 33 are:

```
typedef bool Not
struct Exp {
  1: string left
  2: Not not
  3: BinaryOp op
  4: AnyValue right
}
```

I am using the most recent Thrift version 0.9.2

Comment: I believe `Not` is a type so it may be ok... but `not` is the attribute name (this part is definitely not ok... )... I don't think this thrift will work with many languages. Also... I will suggest to avoid even types with such names.

Comment: Just avoid common language keywords... that should be easy...  right ?

Comment: I don't want to change the processing code only because of a faulty js converter.

Comment: Are you serious... You are saying its Thrift's fault even when you are making the most fundamentally absurd mistake breaking all the guidelines and foundations of the world of programming.

Comment: Please learn to respect tools like Thrift... you may not understand its importance now.

Comment: dear Sarvesh, first, it would be absurd if it was part of the documented constraints or limitations. Which is not. Actually "not" is the semantic needed hence this is the language and in this case the thrift generator to cope with that. This model will work with most languages like Java, Scala and so forth. So, it's definitively not a limitation nor a user's wrong behavior. Javascript has the ability to handle this by using dict access as string. So if the converter is not able to deal with that, it is a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to **not use the reserved language keyword**, as advised by the Thrift compiler. These keywords are reserved for a reason. Thrift is a cross-language tool, and `not` is indeed a keyword in some of them.

> *I don't want to change the processing code only because of a faulty js converter.*

I beg to differ. *Faulty* is something that does not work, altough it should. Thrift clearly tells you that what you are about to try is *illegal* (as of today) and what the problem is.

To put it another way: With Linux, you can put uppercase and lowercase letters in a file name (actually you can put a whole bunch of strange things in, but I'll make it easy). So creating a `FILE` and a `file` in the same folder will work perfectly. If you now take your program and run it on Windows, relying on that behaviour, you will sooner or later run into trouble and may start to complain you "*dont want to change your processing code only because of that faulty OS*".

Note that complaining will not help you out of the pothole, altough the endorphines emitted during that process will make sure you have a fun time. The solution is of course to wait until Microsoft fixed their faulty OS, because you make the rules. Correct?

Of course not. So if you feel the implementation is wrong - fine! This is Open Source, and nobody claimed perfection. [You are free to provide a patch](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute), and we will happily review it. But please make sure you tested it with all 20+ languages currently supported by Thrift.

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you have a reference for this advise please?
Indeed, it's open source and collaborating is an option and for that we need to know if it's actually needed, right?
The thing is that keywords management is tricky since new languages can come up with new ones. Let say, scala has `_` and we all know the great Underscore.js! This is whty the scala generator handle cases like this using backticks. 
Given that, it's reasonable to assume that languages having workarounds can use them (string based access in js). 
Note that: `not` is not a *thrift* keyword.
(it's not a rant ^^)

Comment: However, I see `not` in [this file](https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob_plain;f=compiler/cpp/src/thriftl.ll;hb=281bdae6b2e40694db57f19b0ee13eb51b575c39).

I guess it means `not` is a **thrift** keyword!! If it's correct, I just cannot find the official Thrift documentation about reserved words :-/. Any pointer is welcome.

Thanks for your time

Comment: [Only in the sources](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=compiler/cpp/src/thriftl.ll;hb=HEAD) (look for `thrift_reserved_keyword`). There's no explicit doc about it that I'm aware of, but OTOH the message is quite precise and surely enough to act upon. "*The thing is that keywords management is tricky since new languages can come up with new ones*" - Exactly. BTW, we already have a number of language specific issues w/regard to reserved words or constructs covered, but there's still room for improvements. Hence the call for patches :-)

Comment: ... if I had a wish, I would envision Thrift to cover all naming conflicts automatically and the reserved keywords stripped down to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the not to something else, i think the problem is that 'not' may have another meaning in the language that you choose to generate.

```
2: Not not
```